# C++ find in tree by path

Tags: c++, recursion

I want to find a node (Frame-object) in a tree. I have the path as string and the root-path (parent) as input params, here is my code:

```
  Frame* TryFindFrame(const char* framePath, const Frame* pParentFrame)
  {
    const Frame* pResult = NULL;
    foreach(const Frame* pChildFrame, pParentFrame->ChildFrames)
    {
          if(pChildFrame->HasPath)
          {
            LPCTSTR framePathObj = NULL;
            pChildFrame->GetPath(&framePathObj);
            if(framePathObj != NULL)
            {
              // found it
              if(strcmp(framePathObj, framePath) == 0)  
              {
                pResult = pChildFrame;
                break;
              }
              else
              {
                pResult = TryFindFrame(framePath, pChildFrame);
              }

            }
          } 

    }
    return pResult;
  }
```

The problem is that the function returns NULL when the path is longer then 2 elements like "my::test::path" cause after the path is found another recursion is executed and the pResult is assigned NULL.

How can I end the recursion when I found the frame by my path?

Comment: You realize this compiles for no one but you, much less actually runs and exhibits the behavior you're describing, right? Regardless, without knowing what  `GetPath` actually *does* the best you can hope for is wild guesses. Mine is this: you're looking for a full path, but only comparing against parent + immediate child on the first hop. `root::child::subchild`, the node at `child` will report a full path of `root::child` *only*. You need to parse your input frame path and compare "up to delimiter" against the full-path returned from the child's `GetPath` call.

Comment: No, sorry, each frame has the fullpath stored as variable. So GetPath returns the full path to which I can compare the inputpath to. My problem is that the recursion does not stop when I found the path which I actually do.

Comment: After I found my Frame with this code `if(strcmp(framePathObj, framePath) == 0)` the function does not exit, it runs the last recursion again and overwrites my result, so I guess I need a better ending condition for the recursion.

Comment: Look at what the code does *after* `pResult = TryFindFrame(framePath, pChildFrame);` It appears to continue in the for-loop regardless of whether you found your target or not. I think adding `&& !pResult` to the for-loop condition, or after the if-child-has-path closing brace, `if (pResult) break;` may be what is missing (and in the process, you can remove the `break;` after the child-assignment clause). Again, just a guess, as this code is near-greek to me (no offense to the greeks).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit strange how your code even compiles, because you implicitly convert `const Frame* pResult` to `Frame*` when returning it.

Also the algorithm is far from optimal. You could store in the frame only a part of path corresponding to that frame. Then when you search you split the path into parts, and check parts agains node values, so you don't have to traverse unneeded subtrees.

Anyway, provided you can't change the `Frame` class, change your code like this:

```
  const Frame* TryFindFrame(const char* framePath, const Frame* pParentFrame)
  {
    foreach(const Frame* pChildFrame, pParentFrame->ChildFrames)
    {
          if(pChildFrame->HasPath)
          {
            LPCTSTR framePathObj = NULL;
            pChildFrame->GetPath(&framePathObj);
            if(framePathObj != NULL)
            {
              // found it
              if(strcmp(framePathObj, framePath) == 0)  
              {
                return pChildFrame;
              }
              else
              {
                const Frame* pResult = TryFindFrame(framePath, pChildFrame);
                if (pResult)
                  return pResult;
              }
            }
          } 

    }
    return NULL;
  }
```